# Finding good and effective solution for overhead RCC slab spalling due to corrosion in Rebars

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete

Please suggest some effective repair solution for spalling overhead slab due to high corrosion in rebars.

[image: Spalling Slab with corroded rebars]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! While I agree with [@kamran's answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/25868/1832) (this situation desperately and urgently requires the intervention of a professional engineer on site to inspect the location), this question can't be appropriately answered by strangers online, so I'm closing it as off-topic. But seriously, **get an engineer to look into this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's eminently dangerous. I would immediately inform the authorities of unsafe condition of the structure and request immediate evacuation of the building, had I observed something like this.

Next step would be shoring up by a qualified contractor and adding beams or demolition and reconstruction of the slab per instructions of an engineer.

I would try to find out the reason for this defect to correct it for reconstruction.